# powershell: how to expose some parameters defined in the main script to all the modules to be called

Tags: powershell, global-variables

The main calling script defines 3 parameters, and I'd like all the module can use them, one way is to use global script, but looks bad.

I hope we can use something like the following to pass the parameters, but doesn't work

```
  import-module "$currentPath\ETLLib.psm1" $a $b $c
```

my main script is like:

```
$a  
$b  
$c  
import-module "$currentPath\ETLLib.psm1" $a $b $c  
import-module "$currentPath\Tranform.psm1"  $a $b $c
```

ETLLib.psm1

```
param($a $b $c)
```

Tranform.psm1

```
param($a $b $c)
```

Answer (score 7):

The `ArgumentList` parameter of `Import-Module` should be used.

Test.psm1:

```
param($a, $b, $c)
Write-Host $a
Write-Host $b
Write-Host $c
```

Import using `ArgumentList`:

```
Import-Module Test -ArgumentList arg1, arg2, arg3
```

Output:

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
```